# Is it possible to access clipboard when running program remotely, through e.g. wmic or psexec?

Tags: windows, remote, clipboard

I have administrative rights on two computers in domain, suppose there is trivial `s.bat` on one of them in home directory:

```
echo 123 > 123.txt
echo 123 | clip
```

If execution is initiated from 2nd computer, e.g. like this:

```
WMIC /node:10.10.10.100 process call create 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\users\me\s.bat','c:\users\me'
```

then text file is created, but nothing is copied to clipboard. If it's security issue, can it be overcome, or is it some other error on my side?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is allowed, but instead of echoing `123`, try echoing the response from `whoami.exe`.  Does the `123.txt` output file indicate your user context?  If not, then you may need `/implevel:Impersonate` when calling `wmic.exe`.  However, if so, then you may also need to use `/privileges:ENABLE` and `/interactive:ON` command-line switches.  Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, @leeharvey1, adding 3 switches you suggested produced same output from `whoami` (found in text file) if run remotely, but still no success with clipboard. However, I see that when `whoami` is run locally on target PC, "I" (domain\user) belong, among others, to groups `NT AUTHORITY\REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON`, `NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE` and `LOCAL`; and if run remotely, to `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK` and `NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication`. Other groups match. I wonder if clipboard access requires membership of, I suspect, LOCAL.